# How can I use FileInputStream to read a audio file into an array with 2 bytes data

Tags: java, char, inputstream

In another word, the file was write with PCM_16bit, but those data was store as 8-bit. I want to ananlyze this file with dsp, but how can I read this file in 16 bit a time and form this 16bit as one integer from 0-65535.

Comment: What makes you think FileInputStream has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if what you want is to read two-bytes at a time as a single unsigned value, you can use something like this:

```
File f = new File("/path/to/file");
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    while (true){
        values.add(dis.readUnsignedShort());
    }
} catch(EOFException e){
    /* you've read everything at this point */
} finally {
    dis.close();
}
```

You can change `values` into a primitive array at that point, or just work with the list directly.

Comment: Thank you! The situation is I have a audio file which is created by Audiorecord(java) and the way of encode I choose is PCM_16bit. So the data should be 2 byte for each amplitude value. And I need analyze that sound, such as FFT. So I'd like to change this audio to an array. But  I'm new to java. I don't know how to change 16 bit data in to an array.

Comment: After I see the doc of DataInputStream, I think this question is so foolish. But Still thank you for your answer.